# Content script to update specific tab popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

Let's have an imaginary extension which takes everything after '/' from url, which is done in content script. Also updates badge and change text in popup.html, which different for every tab (different tab, diff. url)

*contentscript.js:*

```
var str = document.URL;
var n = str.lastIndexOf('/');
var result = str.substring(n + 1);
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: "result", url: result});
```

*eventpage.js:*

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message == "result") {
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({tabId:sender.tab.id, "text" : "1"});      
      links = request.url;
        }
```

*popup.js:*

```
$(function () {
    var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    $('#total').text(bg.links);
});
```

*popup.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Plugin</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='total'>Nothing</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works only on new loaded tabs, not when I click between them. For example, when I load first page "webpage.com/first" my popup's got 'first'. When I load second page(on different tab) "webpage.com/second" popup is 'second'. After that I click on the first page (on the first tab) and my popup is 'second' which I meant to be 'first'.

//badge in my project is counter, I wrote it here only for getting an idea

Comment: 1. `{message: "result"}` should be `{message: "result", url: result}` 2. You have only one global `links` variable in the background page so of course it only stores the last set value. 3. The content scripts are only executed once when the tab is loaded, not on every tab switch

Comment: to 3. I know it's executed once, but I'm finding a way how make popup.html to be different on every tab

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to get the tab url you can do it without content scripts just by using [chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) in popup.js:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    $('#total').text(tabs[0].url.replace(/^.+?\/([^\/]*)$/, '$1'));
});
```

Otherwise use [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) in popup.js:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: "document.querySelector('p.something').textContent"
}, function(results) {
    $('#something').text(results[0]);
});
```

Both methods require [`"activeTab"` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) in manifest.json.